# Why codebuild.sh fails to run my local build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to test locally my build without needing to upload my code all over the time. Therefore, I downloaded the [`codebuild.sh`](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/local_builds/codebuild_build.sh) into my ubuntu machine and places into `~/.local/bin/codebuild_build`.

Then I made it executable via:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/codebuild_build
```

And with the following `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  pre_build:
   commands:
     - docker login -u $USER -p $TOKEN
  build:
    commands:
     - docker build -f ./dockerfiles/7.0.8/Dockerfile -t myapp/php7.0.8:$(cat VERSION_PHP_708) -t myapp/php7.0.8:latest .
     - docker build -f ./dockerfiles/7.0.8/Dockerfile_develop -t myapp/php7.0.8-dev:$(cat VERSION_PHP_708) -t myapp/php7.0.8-dev:latest .
     - docker build -f ./dockerfiles/7.2/Dockerfile -t myapp/php7.0.8:$(cat VERSION_PHP_72) -t myapp/php7.0.8:latest .
     - docker build -f ./dockerfiles/7.2/Dockerfile_develop -t myapp/php7.0.8-dev:$(cat VERSION_PHP_708) -t myapp/php7.0.8-dev:latest .
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push etable/php7.2
      - docker push etable/php7.2-dev
      - docker push etable/php7.0.8
      - docker push etable/php7.0.8-dev
```

I tried to execute my command like that:

```
codebuild_build -i amazon/aws-codebuild-local -a /tmp/artifacts/docker-php -e .codebuild -c ~/.aws
```

But I get the following output:

```
Build Command:

docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e "IMAGE_NAME=amazon/aws-codebuild-local" -e "ARTIFACTS=/tmp/artifacts/docker-php" -e "SOURCE=/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/docker-php" -v "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/docker-php:/LocalBuild/envFile/" -e "ENV_VAR_FILE=.codebuild" -e "AWS_CONFIGURATION=/home/pcmagas/.aws" -e "INITIATOR=pcmagas" amazon/aws-codebuild-local:latest

Removing agent-resources_build_1 ... done
Removing agent-resources_agent_1 ... done
Removing network agent-resources_default
Removing volume agent-resources_source_volume
Removing volume agent-resources_user_volume
Creating network "agent-resources_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "agent-resources_source_volume" with local driver
Creating volume "agent-resources_user_volume" with local driver
Creating agent-resources_agent_1 ... done
Creating agent-resources_build_1 ... done
Attaching to agent-resources_agent_1, agent-resources_build_1
build_1  | 2020/01/16 14:43:58 Unable to initialize (*errors.errorString: AgentAuth was not specified)
agent-resources_build_1 exited with code 10
Stopping agent-resources_agent_1 ... done
Aborting on container exit...
```

My ~/.aws has the following files:

```
$ ls -l /home/pcmagas/.aws
σύνολο 8
-rw------- 1 pcmagas pcmagas  32 Αυγ   8 17:29 config
-rw------- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 116 Αυγ   8 17:34 credentials
```

Whilst the config has the following:

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1
```

And `~/.aws/credentials` is in the following format:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ^KEY_ID_CENSORED^
aws_secret_access_key = ^ACCESS_KEY_CENSORED^
```

Also in the `.codebuild` I contain the required docker-login params:

```
USER=^CENCORED^
TOKEN=^CENCORED^
```

Hence, I can get the params required for docker-login.

Do you have any idea why I the build fails to run locally?

Answer (score 0):

Your pre-build step has a command that logs you in to docker

```
docker login -u $USER -p $TOKEN
```

Make sure that you have included the docker login credentials in your local file environment file.

Comment: In the `.codebuild ` I include theese params as well. Also, my question is edited as well.

Comment: Also, the error shows no info regarding `docker login` It is about aws credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Change the environment variable name in '.codebuild' file, e.g.:

```
DOCKER_USER=^CENCORED^
DOCKER_TOKEN=^CENCORED^
```

It seems the CodeBuild agent is interpreting the 'TOKEN' environment variable itself.